# Proper shebang of python script running on Windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

Python scripts running on Linux machines have this shebang on top.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

For Windows, what is the proper shebang to use on top? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: See the documentation about the use of [Shebang Lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines) on Windows. Note that it only does something if the script is run using the `py` command on that OS.

Comment: There's no equivalent of "/usr/bin" in Windows, so using an explicit shebang isn't recommended.  The launcher supports virtual shebangs that use the Windows registry to a find a particular Python version. The simplest is without a path, e.g. `#!python3`. It also supports virtual Unix paths such as `#!/usr/bin/python3` and `#!/usr/bin/env python`. The latter searches `PATH`.

Comment: The primary reason for the shebang on Linux is that operating system can execute text files directly by simply typing `./filename`, assuming that file has the execute permission bit set, and needs to know which interpreter to use, e.g. Python, Bash, etc. In Windows/DOS, the only files you can run that way are batch files (`.bat`).

Comment: @JVines, please put your comment as an answer so that the bounty can be awarded to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of the shebang lines on Linux (and Unix like machines) is done by the operating system, and Windows doesn't do that, so there is no proper shebang line.

So if you don't want to do something special like selecting a particular Python version for your program, you can leave out the shebang (or leave in the one you need for running on Linux).

If your `.py` files are registered on Windows to be started by a particular Python executable,  it is possible to check the first line of that file and interpret it to make sure you start the right version.

It is possible to start another Python version in that way with the original file and other arguments, but keep in mind that if you use that to start e.g a Python 2.7 interpreter where Python 3.8 is the one registered, that your Python program must be valid Python for both versions (so no `print` statements, `f'{somevar}'` strings, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, the proper shebang to use is actually the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Python uses "[virtual shebangs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)", which allows certain specific "Unix-style" shebang lines to be portable between Unix and Windows.

On Windows, you need to either associate `.py` files with any Python executable, or run python scripts using "The Python Launcher" (the `py.exe` command).

Once you associate .py files with any Python executable (or use `py.exe`), you can execute python files directly by simply typing `myscript.py` or double clicking it in Windows Explorer.  Then, the virtual shebang will be used to execute the script with the designated Python executable.

Comment: Mind that in Linux as well as Windows, the "safer" option for a python shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`, because it's path independent.

Answer (score 1):

Using a python extension in VSCode or any other IDE ,set the path to your interpreter as the first line of code
Windows 10.python 3.9

```
#!C:/Users/waithira/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
print('hello world')
```